# Difference between two dates for individual business months

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

**Objective/ Problem**: How can I determine the difference/ remaining days (workday) between today and the end of a individual business month within a dax measure?

**Info / General**: I have a calendar table in PowerPivot that shows me per day what business month it is and whether it is a workday day. This table has the following structure:
Date - Business Month - Workday factor.

That is, each business month has a different start and end date, as opposed to the normal month.

**Previous approach**:
I think I first have to find a variable that shows me the maximum date per month and then use calculate and filter to find the difference to today?

How would you implement that?

Best Regards

Edit: That is my actual approach:
Start Date:

```
Calculate(MIN(Calendar[Business Month]))
```

End Date:

```
Calculate(Max(Calendar[Business Month]))
```

That ones show me the start and end date for each Business Month.
Now I need to figure out, how many workdays are between today and End Date.

The Calendar looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8383r.png)

```
Workday = 1
Day off = 0
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. Could you show us your input?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. It seems like you're well underway sorting your own problem already. Can you show us your formula's or VBA code that has gotten you this far? I'm afraid we're not here to write your code for you, but we can definitely help improve your efforts. In your case [I suggest starting here](https://www.iqaccountingsolutions.com/blog/calculating-difference-two-dates-excel/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

You are nearly there, you need to combine the functions:

```
Total Working Days = 
VAR maxMonth = MAX(Calendar[Business Month])
VAR minMonth = MIN(Calendar[Business Month])
RETURN
CALCULATE(SUM('Calendar'[Workday Factor]), FILTER('Calendar', [Date] >= minMonth && [Date] <= maxMonth))
```

I also recommend that you create a calendar dimension that has your standard calendar and business calendar in it, and nay logic around it, like current day/week/month/year, quarters, or periods and use that to connect to your data table

Hope that helps

Comment: Awesome, thanks! But I get the error, that DAX does not support comparing between date and text values for your part: [Date]>= minMonth. Do you know why?

Comment: Does someone have some idea?

Comment: I recreated your dataset in Power and it worked? Some thing is being evaluated as text in your Power BI Workbook, Check the Power Query datatype and formatting options

Comment: Thanks for your replay! Could you please check my example file?https://gofile.io/?c=Q5AFqN

Comment: Sorry I can't access the data model in Excel, I don't have the add in I'm Power BI Desktop

Comment: There is the calendar table in the first sheet. Maybe you can add that in power bi?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want is to calculate the number of day between today and 
 the end of a selected business month.

So If you select with a slicer a particular Month you can use dax time intelligence.

```
Measure = Calculate(Sum(CalendarCustom[WorkDay Factor]),CalendarCustom[Date] > NOW())
```

Calculate function let you add filter to a table and evaluate this filtered table.
Here the table will be filtered by your slicers for the Monthselected and you just have to add filter to be sure that your date is greater than today.